# HoNew firebase create path using this method in iOS?

Tags: ios, firebase

I am using objective C but I tried more but it did not helps. Someone tell me how add:

```
self.ref.child("users").child(user!.uid).setValue(["username": username])
```

Answer (score 1):

Before sending the value to fire base.we should add like this it helps me.

```
self.firebase = [[self.firebase child:@"chat"]  child:app.GSetChannelId];
```